# 2nd column not sorted in sql query where i use case statement in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

The below sample query I got from stackoverflow, which is helpful. I am using the same scenario and it's partially resolved.

Working query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Requirements
ORDER BY 
     CASE Day 
         WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
         WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 4
         WHEN 'Friday' THEN 5
         WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 6
         WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
     END
```

My query output is as below, my table has duplicate values, Monday1 is returning after Monday1, but why Tuesday1 is being returned before Tuesday?

```
Monday
Monday1
Tuesday1
Tuesday
Wednesday
Wednesday1
```

My table with two column values looks as this:

```
Monday      Monday
Monday      Monday1
Wednesday   Wednesday
Wednesday   Wednesday1
Tuesday     Tuesday
Tuesday     Tuesday1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tuesday1 nor Monday1 are caught by your case statement in the order by, they should be evaluated as null and come out at the top - try also evaluating your CASE in the SELECT, then you can see what values it gets  e.g. SELECT *, CASE WHEN... etc ..END AS MySortOrder FROM...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question risks being downvoted/closed due to a lack of clarity in your question. Please consider rewording to make it more clear what you are asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add the original column to the order by, something like `ORDER BY CASE ... END, columnname`.

Answer (score 2):

Add your column with `Monday1` and etc to ORDER BY statement:

```
;WITH Requirements AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('Monday','Monday'),
('Monday','Monday1'),
('Wednesday','Wednesday'),
('Wednesday','Wednesday1'),
('Tuesday','Tuesday'),
('Tuesday','Tuesday1')
) as t([day], col2)
)

SELECT * 
FROM Requirements
ORDER BY 
     CASE Day 
         WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
         WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 4
         WHEN 'Friday' THEN 5
         WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 6
         WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
     END , col2
```

Output:

```
day         col2
Monday      Monday
Monday      Monday1
Tuesday     Tuesday
Tuesday     Tuesday1
Wednesday   Wednesday
Wednesday   Wednesday1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only sorting on the first column, the second column is not involved in any ORDER BY, therefore there is no rule as to how column2 is ordered.  Column1 is ordered as expected.  If you wanted Monday1 after Monday, add column2 as a second ORDER BY parameter

Comment: I got it resolved by adding the second column in order by as mentioned in your posts. Thanks to all.